# How do you store row information in a CSR matrix when there are gaps in the rows

Tags: math, data-structures, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I am reading on sparse matrix formats and there is something I don;t understand.

All resources I find claim that the representation is:

```
values
col_indices
row_ranges
```

Where `values` and `col_indices` have the same amount of elements and `row_ranges` has exactly `row_dim + 1` entries indicating where each row starts.

Am I correct to assume that when there are gaps in the rows you just duplicate the next index? For example

```
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
```

Should be:

```
values = [1, 1]
cols = [0, 3]
row_ranges = [0,1,1,1,2]
```

Such that the 2 middle ranges `[1,1]` have an extent of 0, indicating the row is empty?

Comment: yes, `row_ranges` is the number of rows plus 1, and its values will be static or increasing.  In a large realistic CSR, empty rows are uncommon, but allowed in the format and calculations.